# MongoDB ошибка вставки объекта класса

Tags: python, классы, mongodb

Ошибка при добавлении объекта класса. Я не могу разобраться что не так. Прошу помощи

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

Вот сам класс:

```
 import Date as date


    class Ticket:
        def __init__(self, name, surname, destination, date):
            self.name = name
            self.surname = surname
            self.destination = destination
            self.date = date
    
        def print(self):
            print("________________________")
            print("Name: ", getattr(Ticket, "name", "Name"))
            print("Surname: ", getattr(Ticket, "surname", "Surname"))
            print(
                "Destination: ", getattr(Ticket, "destination", "Destination")
            )
            print(
                "Date: ",
            )
```

Код добавления:

```
import pymongo
import Ticket

DB_Client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

Aeroport_DB = DB_Client["ADB"]
collection = Aeroport_DB["Tickets"]


class Aeroport:
    def add_ticket(self):
        n = input("Enter name: ")
        s = input("Enter surname: ")
        d = input("Enter destination: ")
        print("Date")
        day = int(input("Enter day: "))
        month = int(input("Enter month: "))
        year = int(input("Enter year: "))
        dt = Ticket.date.Date(day, month, year)
        obj = Ticket.Ticket(n, s, d, dt)

        collection.insert_one(obj)


collection.drop()
```

Comment: Приведите **полный стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе**. Гадать, на какое место кода ругается ошибка - далеко не всегда благодарное занятие. А вообще судя по всему от вас ожидается словарь формата "поле: значение", а не то, что вы передаёте.

Comment: Ругаетcя на insert_one(obj)

Comment: Ну вот `insert_one` ожидает словарь формата `{'name': 'имя', 'surname': 'фамилия', ... }` и так все поля